# Is it possible to flag a container that it should restart when another container is restarted?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using `docker-compose` to deploy a project which contains about 15 containers.

I would like to configure that `container b` must be restarted whenever `container a` is restarted. Is that possible to configure in `docker-compose.yml`? I have been going through the docs, but I cannot find anything useful.

In this case, `container b` can be restarted whenever `container a` is restarted; that is, there is no need to wait for a certain health check of `container a`.

If this is not possible directly in `docker-compose.yml`, is there a useful docker project/image which can be used for this?

Comment: A not-so-straight way to achieve this is to subscribe Docker events in container b, and watch the restart event of container a.